# How to create object inside of dynamically parameters with some process?

Tags: c#, initialization

I get several errors when I create object from MyMenu class

I wanna that in the ctor

- Id parameter will increase automatically
- When I create object, it should add to MyMenuList

Would you mind telling me the correct way?

#### My menu class properties

```
public abstract class MenuProperties
{
    public byte Id { get; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubMenu { get; set; }
    public abstract void AddMenu(MyMenu menu);
    public abstract void DeleteMenu(MyMenu menu);
    public List<MyMenu> MyMenuList { get; set; }
}
public class MyMenu : MenuProperties
{
    public MyMenu()
    {
       Id++; //it's always 0
       MyMenuList.Add(this); // How to fix here, stackoverflow error when I run it
    }

    public override void AddMenu(MyMenu menu)
    {
        MyMenuList.Add(menu); 
    }

    public override void DeleteMenu(MyMenu menu)
    {
        MyMenuList.Remove(menu);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.Id.ToString() + " " + MenuName.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

#### How I am using it

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyMenu menu = new MyMenu
        {
            Id = 0,
            IsSubMenu = false,
            MenuName = "Default",
        };
        MyMenu menu1 = new MyMenu
        {
            Id = 1,
            IsSubMenu = false,
            MenuName = "Home",
        };
        MyMenu menu2 = new MyMenu
        {
            Id = 2,
            IsSubMenu = false,
            MenuName = "Settings",
        };
        MyMenu menu3 = new MyMenu
        {
            Id = 3,
            IsSubMenu = true,
            MenuName = "Add Menu",
        };
        MyMenu menu4 = new MyMenu
        {
            Id = 4,
            IsSubMenu = true,
            MenuName = "Remove Menu",
        };
        menu.AddMenu(menu);// I wanna just remove this methods
        menu1.AddMenu(menu1);// But When I create object from MyMenu class
        menu2.AddMenu(menu2);// I wanna add this object to any list when 
        menu3.AddMenu(menu3);// its created.
        menu4.AddMenu(menu4);// I am thinking, it can be in ctor
        //But I am taking error.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

There can be a lot of logic error bcs of I am a newbie. But When I see negative votes. Its makes me sad so much. Btw I describe my language is so low anyway.

Comment: Can you show the code that uses these classes?

Comment: I added it, but I became demoralized bcs of votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MyMenuList` and a counter should be a static member of the `MyMenu` class.
I don't know what you would use the `MyMenuList` list, this way there is no point of it at all. Every instance would only have one item in it's list; itself. Also, it doesn't make sense to reference a child type of an abstract class. You should have a list of `MenuProperties` instead of `MyMenu`. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
public abstract class MenuProperties
{
    private static byte LastId = 0;
    public static List<MenuProperties> MyMenuList { get; } = new List<MenuProperties>();

    public byte Id { get; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubMenu { get; set; }

    protected MenuProperties()
    {
        Id = LastId++;
    }

    public abstract void AddMenu(MenuProperties menu);
    public abstract void DeleteMenu(MenuProperties menu);
}
public class MyMenu : MenuProperties
{
    public MyMenu()
    {
        //This was not a Stack overflow, the MyMenuList was null; you didn't initialise it.
        MyMenuList.Add(this);
    }

    public override void AddMenu(MenuProperties menu)
    {
        MyMenuList.Add(menu);
    }

    public override void DeleteMenu(MenuProperties menu)
    {
        MyMenuList.Remove(menu);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Id.ToString() + " " + MenuName;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used abstract bcs there can be nested menu. I didn't want to use same properties for every class. for example
- Default
- Home
- Settings > -Add menu
                   - > Remove menu
                   -  > Menu type  - > Removable
                                            - > Editable
and so on.

Comment: I didn't say not to use abstract base class, but you are using it wrong